# record sound in python 3.2?

Tags: python-3.x, audio-recording

I have successfully wrote a code that will record a few seconds of audio and save it in the selected directory in python 2.7 using pyaudio, like so:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "%d_%d.wav" % (self.get('subject_nr'),       self.get('count_inline_script'))

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
            channels = CHANNELS,
            rate = RATE,
            input = True,
            frames_per_buffer = chunk)
```

Now, i only recently started using Python 3.2 and i am wondering if there is a way to record sound like in the older version?

Comment: Perhaps this is clear to some people, but I think it may be helpful if you included what happens when you try and run this in python 3. What errors occur?

Comment: If it is simply the absence of the pyAudio module for python 3, check the sight joaquin linked. It is ridiculously useful for these things. I have used it to hunt up a ton of obscure libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows and your script only uses `wave` and `pyAudio` it is perfectly possible to run it with py3k.
`wave` is a module in the official distribution and windows binary installers for `pyAudio` can be obtained from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)